# Using '%' or wildcard in IN SQL statement Or how to search for multiple text criteria not exact

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have sql:

```
Select * 
from Inventory
Where RowKey like ('%439%)
```

The row key contains text such as: Stock_Id = 439. I need the Status column that is next to the Rowkey column in the table.

I have a list of 40 ids that I need to look for - is there an easier way other than doing RowKey like ('%439%') and changing the number between % 40 times?

I tried

```
Select * 
from Inventory
where rowkey in ('%439%','%5000%')
```

but it doesn't come up with anything.

Edit: Is there a way to include AND condition? Such as 
    Select * 
    from Inventory
    Where RowKey like ('%439%) AND oldvalue = '1'

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could remove the stuff before the last string:

```
where stuff(rowkey, 1, charindex('= ', rowkey) + 1, '') in ('439', '5000')
```

Comment: Edit: It does work after I removed the space. Thanks! Could you explain what stuff does?

Comment: Is there a way to add an AND condition to this? I added NewValue = 10 in my query and it came up with nothing again.

Comment: @user2532928 . . . `stuff()` replaces portions of a string.  It is explained in the documentation.  I don't know what `NewValue` is, but this should work with other conditions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to static numbers `BETWEEN` certain values you could just use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INVENTORY
WHERE SUBSTRING(ROWKEY, CHARINDEX('= ', ROWKEY) + 2, 99) BETWEEN 4390 AND 5000
```

Comment: The rowkey has extra text in it unfortunately (and also stupidly the ids I need to look up are not in sequence). For example the Rowkey text contains things like: Stock_id = 1  Revenue = 1 <br/>   Type = 1

Comment: Whoops, I see what you were saying better now. I edited the answer.

Comment: Oh, I combined the two answers and it worked. Thank you! where substring(RowKey, charindex ('=', rowkey)+2, 99) in ('439', '210198')

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps with a JOIN and a little XML to parse the list

**Example**

```
Declare @List varchar(max) = '439,5000,...'

Select A.*
 From Inventroy A
 Join (
        Select Value = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
        From  (values (Cast('<x>' + replace(@List,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) )) A(x)
        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
      ) B
 On charindex(B.Value,A.RowKey)>0
```